# I don't know why as is used

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

"Santas of many lands" as presented by the entire aecond grade class.

Why is "as" used in that sentence?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Your question as you’ve posed it doesn’t provide enough context for anyone to answer with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

The word "as" is used in this sentence to mean "in the manner" or "in the way" that it could be presented by a class full of second graders to call attention to how different this would be from a presentation of "Santas of many lands" performed by another, more mature or professional group of performers.

If the word "as" were not in the sentence, then "'Santas of many lands' presented by the entire second grade class" would be a mere factual statement of what happened. It would not call attention and emphasis to the way that second graders would perform it in contrast to other possible performers.